# How to install mono 3 on Debian testing?

Tags: linux, mono, debian

I want to compile the Unreal Engine on my Debian Liunx (testing) box, which needs the *mono* package `libmono-corlib4.0-cil` installed that depends on the mono-runtime in version 3.

However, on my Debian box I have installed mono in version 4 and `libmono-corlib4.5-cil` (4.5 instead of 4.0). So I tried to install that specific version via

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-corlib4.0-cil
```

However, that gives me:

*libmono-corlib4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (< 3.2.9) but 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-8 is to be installed*

Can I install mono-runtime in version 3 alongside the currently installed version 4, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used packages from stable Debian release to build UE.

In order to install `libmono-corlib4.0-cil` from stable:

1. Add stable package repository into your `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install `aptitude` if you don't have it
4. Run `sudo aptitude -t stable install libmono-corlib4.0-cil`

If you have some packages newer then `libmono-corlib4.0-cil` requires, `aptitude` will report an error and ask you what to do. In one of the solutions it will suggest to downgrade those packages to appropriate version. Use that solution and you will get `libmono-corlib4.0-cil` installed.

You may also edit file `Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Setup.sh` inside your directory with UE sources and replace line (should be 78th)

```
sudo apt-get install -y $DEP
```

with

```
sudo aptitude -t stable install $DEP
```

And then rerun `Setup.sh` script. This may help you avoiding similar problems with other packages required by UE.

There may be a way to do everything with `apt-get`, but I don't know it.

And I'm afraid this way won't allow you to have both versions of mono-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, and you don't need to do anything special. In fact, the usual Debian and Ubuntu repositories typically do have several versions of each package (from `oldstable/stable/testing/unstable` or `dapper/hardy/lucid/maverick/natty`). The distributions only have a single package in each version's index file (the Packages files), but you don't have to follow suit.

Of course, `apt-get install myapp` will only install the latest version (unless configured otherwise). You can run apt-get install `myapp=1.42` to force the installation of version 1.42.

Caveat: if all the versions have the same package name, you can't have more than one installed at the same time. If this is important, give each version a different package name: `myapp-1.42`, `myapp-1.43`, etc. Debian and Ubuntu do this for major versions of libraries, where you may need more than one if you have executables linked with different libraries (e.g. `libcap1` and `libcap2`), as well as for a few other packages such as the kernel.

Comment: Ok, but how can I find out which versions are available for a certain package? For example, I ran `apt-cache show mono-runtime`, which told me that there is only version 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-8 available.

Comment: try `apt-cache madison mono-runtime`

Comment: Same result, only that single version.

Comment: Then you need to add older repositories to your sources.list and then `apt-get update`